# не хватает прав просмотра каталога c:\users из powershell

Tags: powershell

Здравствуйте,

имеется скрипт архивации логов,  он успешно работает с любым каталогом, кроме 
c:\users, где хранятся профили

пишет "access dinied"

запуск из-под админа не помогает,
Get-ExecutionPolicy -> Unrestricted

что можно предпринять?

скрипт:

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "4"
$TargetFolder = "c:\users"
$Extension = "*.log"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse  | Where     {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
 foreach ($File in $Files) 
    {
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
        { 
    if ($File.Fullname.Contains("Live")){
    $cmdline = "7z a -tzip -sdel "+'"'+$File+".zip"+'" '+'"'+$File+'"'
    Invoke-Expression $cmdline
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно, у вас и правда нет прав доступа к чужим профилям. Администратор имеет право стать владельцем любого файла - а владелец файла имеет право менять разрешения - но это не означает что администратор имеет доступ к любому файлу изначально.

---

Менять права доступа на чужие профили - идея плохая, потому что это может многое поломать.

Где-то в панели управления была настройка "простой доступ к файлам", если ее не выключать - у администратора будет доступ к чужим профилям.

Также вы можете попробовать сделать службу (windows service) и запустить ее от имени системной учетной записи - у системной учетной записи по умолчанию есть права на чтение всех файлов (но их тоже можно отобрать).

Еще можно попробовать дать самому себе привилегию *SeBackupPrivilege* в настройках локальной политики безопасности или включить себя в группу *Backup Operators* (русского перевода не знаю) - это даст возможность читать любые файлы независимо от настроек доступа к ним.